Recycler View Item automatically starting an action after the previous item has finished its action
People were confused with my earlier question so let me ask it in another way.
I have created items using recyclerview. Now each item contains an edit text and a button.What i want is that after I've pressed the done button the cursor goes over to the next item in the recyclerview .

Please [edit] your question and provide all code that is necessary to reproduce your problem in the question itself. Links to code on external sites are not enough.

If you add code will be easier but one way on the top of my mind is: in the action for that button you need to reference the parent who will be the recyclerview item, found the index of it on the List of Items, add 1, reference the childs, identify the one that is edit text and activate that

The most important part is still missing: You need to provide a [mre] so we can reproduce the issu.

just call this method from your recyclerView object after click method
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position + 1);

remember you have to call it in Ui thread and in your activity class that can access to your recyclerView object
